# Mac eclipse always jump to declaration on copy and paste

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am using eclipse Juno in Mac OSX system .

Its like eclipse in windows system but something keeps annoying me . When I copy and paste some codes , It occasionally jumps to declaration position with the highlighted variable while I am pasting .

My exactly actions are , 
mouse highlighted a segment of codes -> command + c (copy) -> to the position I am gonna paste
-> command + v (paste) .
It always happened to the command + v before I pressed the v , so that I pasted the code overwrite the declaration .

Maybe there is some hotkey I dont know that I triggered . Can anyone help me with this , please .